# Can i use a 32 Bit ODBC Driver for my 64 Bit app

Tags: winapi, odbc, 32bit-64bit

I have a Win32 application that makes ODBC-Connections. We connect using `SQLDriverConnect()`
which displays a dialog to select the data source. In the x64-Version the Dialog shows and offers 2 different 32 Bit MS ACCESS Drivers. When i select one of these, in the 32 Bit version i would see a open file dialog to select a .mdb file. In the 64 Bit version the call to SQLDriverConnect() at this point returns with -1.

`SQLError()` returns: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Is it in general possible to use a 32 Bit ODBC Driver from a 64-Bit executable? Why are these driver shown? As far as i can find there is no 64 Bit MS Access OBDC driver so far. What can i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely cannot mix 32bit application and 64bit driver (or vice-versa).

Basically, an ODBC driver is, typically, a dll (windows) or a shared object (linux...) which is loaded by its parent application.

All executables, dlls, etc that share the same process space must be the same bit'ness...

Comment: Thanks for that clear answer. I was nut sure if ODBC uses COM or different interfaces. But why are these drivers listed by the ODBC driver manager when i call it from a 64-Bit Application?

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR It has to do with registry entries.  The Microsoft description is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976

Answer (score 2):

In order to "bridge" from a 64bit application to a 32bit ODBC driver you would need to employ an ODBC to ODBC Bridge such as -

http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-odbc-mt/

This has a 64bit ODBC client component which connects vis sockets to 32bit server components. The server components bridge to a pre-configured 32bit Access ODBC DSN.

Client component can be either on the local machine or a server machine...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why `SQLDriverConnect()` works the way you describe it, but perhaps this Blog post from Microsoft

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/01/21/how-to-get-a-x64-version-of-jet.aspx

can help you a little bit.

Seems there will be no native 64 bit ODBC driver for MS Access in near future, but those ACE components mentioned there may be an alternative.

Comment: The 64bit Office or MS Access 2010 installers do include a 64bit MS Access ODBC Driver, although it is not part of the 64bit MDAC shipped with the 64bit Windows OS'es it seems, although I imagine that may change in later updates. Only last week I installed 64bit MS Access which then enabled me to Link MS Access tables into my 64bit [Virtuoso Server](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) on Windows.

Comment: @hwilliams: thanks for that interesting info, seems the blog post I found is a little bit outdated.

Answer (score -2):

You can't, but you have the alternative to compile your app in 32bits, and use the 32bit odbc driver. In my case, I use GoLang just change GOARCH environment variable **SET GOARCH=386** then compile your project **go build** and your all set.

Comment: No answer to question: "Can i use a 32 Bit ODBC Driver for my 64 Bit app".