# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: odbc, installation, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to open a program for the first time on Windows XP Pro that uses PostgreSQL 9. I'm getting an error message that says :

> A problem was encountered while trying to log into or create the
>   production database. Details: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default driver specified

In my ODBC manager, I have a list of User DSN's and System DSN's. I tried installing a postgres odbc driver to see if that would help, but it didn't.

There is a connect.dat file in the program file with a line saying "OLE DB Provider = MSDASQL". Changing this entry alters the error message I get to "Provider cannot be found, it may not be properly installed".

I don't know what provider name to insert to get this to work properly. I have done extensive research on this error to no avail. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone still searching the solution to this problem, start R&D from ODBC Driver section. Check if the driver you specified is there or not.

Comment: This error tells me that there is no driver to run ODBC DSN. Install the given ODBC `DRIVER` MSI and see if error goes away.

Comment: If using powershell to test, make sure to use "Windows Powershell ISE (x86)" instead of "Windows Powershell ISE".

Answer (score 93):

Got this error because I had the Data Source Name in User DSN instead of System DSN
[image]

Comment: And how did your connection settings change? Care to share a code snipped as well?

Answer (score 84):

1. In reference to the error: *[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.*

   That error means that the Data Source Name (DSN) you are specifying in your connection configuration is not being found in the windows registry.

   - It is important that your ODBC driver's executable and linking format (ELF) is the same as your application.  In other words, you need a 32-bit driver for a 32-bit application or a 64-bit driver for a 64-bit application.

     If these do not match, it is possible to configure a DSN for a 32-bit driver and when you attempt to use that DSN in a 64-bit application, the DSN won't be found because the registry holds DSN information in different places depending on ELF (32-bit versus 64-bit).

     Be sure you are using the correct ODBC Administrator tool.  On 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, the default ODBC Administrator tool is in `c:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`.  However, on a 64-bit Windows machine, the default is the 64-bit version.  If you need to use the 32-bit ODBC Administrator tool on a 64-bit Windows system, you will need to run the one found here: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

     Where I see this tripping people up is when a user uses the default 64-bit ODBC Administrator to configure a DSN; thinking it is for a 32-bit DSN.  Then when the 32-bit application attempts to connect using that DSN, "Data source not found..." occurs.
   - It's also important to make sure the spelling of the DSN matches that of the configured DSN in the ODBC Administrator.  One letter wrong is all it takes for a DSN to be mismatched.

     [Here is an article that may provide some additional details](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/3352?q=%22Data%20source%20name%20not%20found%20and%20no%20default%20driver%20specified%22&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=support-kb&utm_term=alch&utm_content=jdbc&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=support-kb&utm_term=alch&utm_content=odbc)

     It may not be the same product brand that you have, however; it is a generic problem that is encountered when using ODBC data source names.
2. In reference to the OLE DB Provider portion of your question, it appears to be a similar type of problem where the application is not able to locate the configuration for the specified provider.

Comment: In short, *even if you're on a x64 bit DEV machine* you'll find it easier to avoid the x64 postgres odbc drivers and use the x86 drivers instead.

Answer (score 19):

The Problem might be from the driver name for example instead of `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver}` try `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}` you can see the name of the driver from administration tool

Comment: This solves my problem. To find your driver exact name and version on 32bit Windows machine go to: `c:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` For 64-bit Windows machine: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` Then go to `Driver` Tab, you will see `Name` `Version` `Company` ... So you need to just write `Name` (no need to write version, the name already has version written with it)

Answer (score 9):

In my case, it was working in **x86** but not in **x64**.

It quite ridiculous, but in x64 the following change had to be added before it would work:

```
x86 -> szDsn = "DRIVER={MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)};
x64 -> szDsn = "DRIVER={MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
```

Note the addition of `*.accdb`.

Comment: FYI: The bold text was causing your asterisks to be hidden, so I changed the formatting around a bit to resolve that.

Comment: You just saved me from throwing my laptop off the balcony sir. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

if you are using IIS, maybe you should try
**"application pools" -->  "DefaultAppPool" --> "application pools default value"
--> "32-Bit-application-activ" --> set false**

Answer (score 4):

I got this with data driven tests using:

```
Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
```

The problem is the above driver only is 32 bit. I had switched visual studio testsettings file to 64 bit to test a 64-bit-only application.

Switching back to 32 bit in the testsettings file fixed the issue.

[using a test settings file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 4):

Check the exact driver name in the ODBC Administrator tool. Press Windows key + R and then:

- `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` on 32-bit systems
- `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` on 64-bit systems

In my case it should have been `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` instead of `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)`.

Answer (score 3):

For me the below worked:

1. Add the linked server as a System DSN (ODBC System Source Administration) e.g. with name -> **TEST_NAME**

[image]

2. Use as **data source** the **TEST_NAME**
   [image]

Comment: This just repeats the top answer.

Answer (score 2):

This was not the first time I have come to this page searching for the same error message.  Unfortunately, Microsoft error messages are vague and often several different issues will cause the same error message, hence why there are so many answers here.

I will propose another solution in case this helps anyone else.

Under Excel Datasource settings I use the following connection string:

```
"ODBC;DSN=jg_report;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

The problem is that when I am opening an ADODB connection in VBA, and I use this same string, it will produce the "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" error.

To correct the connection string, I simply have to remove the "ODBC;" as follows:

```
"DSN=jg_report;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
```

The connection then works as expected without producing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above but found my issue was I used a | in the name of the DSN (I have multipled ODBC connectors - one for each DB - to make sure I don't comingle data)

I replaced the | (pipe) with a _ and all now works fine.

I was trying to call SQL Server from Alteryx.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions here http://help.loftware.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27099554 I had to install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) before I had the Excel driver installed to use the DSN-less connection I wanted to use from perl.

Answer (score 0):

I had the installed drivers listed in `odbcinst -q -d`, and could connect manually but not through R's `odbc::dbConnect()`. Turns out I forgot a semicolon in the connection string: `.connection_string = "TrustServerCertificate=yes;"`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the drivers were missing.
So, installed the latest management studio from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16
Solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I was using Driver={Simba Athena ODBC Driver} but I did not had installed the driver. I downloaded the expected one from Amazon