# Data source name not found and no default driver specified - windows server

Tags: oracle11g, asp-classic

I have installed `win32_11gR2_client` and through a classic asp page I am trying to connect to oracle. 
I have setup the System DSN accordingly. 
But still getting :

> -2147467259  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified error

. I am don't know what is wrong. Have anybody encountered this situation? I am trying this on a Windows 2012 Server. I have the same setup in DEV. It is working there.

I am connecting to Database using :

```
ConnString = "SERVER=" & serverDSN & ";
driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};UID=" & userId & ";PWD=" & userPassword & ";"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Driver Manager\] Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115632/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-drive)

Comment: I have seen that post. Did not solve my issue. I am using ODBC Data Source 32 Bit in administrator mode. I have setup DSN names exactly in System DSN.

Comment: OLEDB connection strings are generally regarded as preferable to ODBC if you are able to install the driver
https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/