# Excel VBA: ODBC Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc

I couldnt connect my vba to the mysql. can you tell me where did I go wrong?
this method raise runtime error "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
my OS is win 7 64 bit and I just installed 64bit ODBC Connector from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-odbc/
but still the error occurs. I also use xampp with no password if that is also need specifying.

```
Sub SqlConnect()
Dim ReturnArray

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim DBPath As String
    Dim sconnect As String


    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    sconnect = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2.2 Driver}; SERVER = localhost;" & _
        "PORT=3306;" & _
        "DATABASE= timeintimeoutdb;" & _
        "UID=root;" & _
        "PWD=;"




    Conn.Open sconnect
        sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM [students]"
        mrs.Open sqlstring, Conn
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
        mrs.Close


    Conn.Close
    End Sub
```

Comment: If your Office is 32-bit then you need the 32-bit MySQL driver.  Most (?) Office installs are 32-bit.

Comment: The connection string is fine. Either driver version (current is MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver) or you have database, uid or pwd wrong.

Comment: This is a rather common error, as @TimWilliams pointed out the driver Version (32-bit) depends on you installed Office Version and not your OS Version, which is rather counterintuitive. Detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115632/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-drive