# tally odbc connection with php and fetch data

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, tally

I am Getting this error when connect with tally with php

**Connection failed: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

My connection code is:-

```
try {
    $shift_db = new PDO("odbc:TallyODBC64_9000");
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Driver Manager\] Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115632/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-drive)

Comment: what is the duplicate here. i am not understand yet.

Comment: Try reading the [top answer to the possible-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25428598/241164)… Quick summary — Is `TallyODBC64_9000` a System DSN? If not, does PHP run as the User who created the User DSN? In either case, is PHP the same bitness (32-bit or 64-bit) as the ODBC driver for that DSN?