# How to connect to SQL Server using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, sqlalchemy, pycharm

In Pycharm I have prepared data in dataframe which i intend to insert in SQL Server using sqlalchemy.
I have done like below

```
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://<ServerName>:<Port>/<DatabaseName>/driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")
df.to_sql('TableName', con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

but I keep getting below error.

> return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

What is mistake I am making?
I am able to connect using `pyodbc.connect` so access should not be issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[Microsoft\]\[ODBC Driver Manager\] Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115632/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-drive)

Comment: Try using `?driver=` instead of `/driver=`