# Anyone know why this error comes up when trying to connect python to sql server with pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, orm, pypyodbc

Error message:

> ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified')
> task is terminated

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker
from collections import defaultdict
import pypyodbc as odbc

DRIVER = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
SERVER_NAME = 'LAPTOP-CMEDO1TK'
DATABASE_NAME = 'fakeData'


conn_string = """
    Driver={DRIVER};
    Server={SERVER_NAME};
    Database={DATABASE_NAME};
    Trusted_Connection=yes;"""

try:
    conn = odbc.connect(conn_string)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("task is terminated")
    sys.exit()
else:
    cursor = conn.cursor
```

Here is my code. I've ran a for loop in python that printed my drivers and I am specifying one of the ones printed.

> SQL Server
> SQL Server Native Client 11.0
> SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0
> ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
> Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
>
> Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
>
> Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
> ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
> ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115632/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-drive) answer

Comment: Thanks that was a useful thread to read through, however it didn't seem to fix my issue. i created a 32-bit driver that connected successfully when I tested it, however it still didn't help my python code run. I tried a 64-bit driver but it failed to connect when I tested the data source. I get this error message in my code now.                                             ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.')
task is terminated

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use `pypyodbc` instead of `pyodbc`? Have you tried `DRIVER = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'` yet?

Comment: No specific reason. To be honest the tutorial I was looking at was using pypyodbc so that is what I went with. I'll look at pyodbc though. I have tried that entry for the Driver. I tried all the ones listed above lol. I also tried variations of this kind of package using sqlalchemy and sql.connector and they gave me connection issues as well. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: The curly brackets are important. Have you tried `DRIVER = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'` yet?

Comment: Have you tried using the path to the driver file instead of the driver name?