# Connect to database-Amazon Redshift DB: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: uipath-studio

Can anyone provides the details solution for the below issue?
When connecting Amazon Redshift database with Uipath Studio getting the below error.That is "Data source name not found and no default driver specified."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IHeR.png)

Getting the solution details.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Name** parameter, you have "*endpoiint*" and there is just an endpoint in the connection string.

Also what happens, when you click on the *Build* ?

Comment: Provide the solution details to resolve this issue.

Comment: when clicking on Build it's going to DSN Page.

Comment: Try fixing Variable Name: "endpoiint" in "endpoint" you have typo "ii" as I can see in the screenshot. When you are passing this in Data Source using connection string, you have server=endpoint (not endpoiint) and that is your variable name

Comment: Already removed duplicate of i and still getting same issue.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115632/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-drive