# User [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source\u001f1 name not found and no default driver specified"] IIS Node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, odbc, iisnode

I encounter this error while testing my MSSQL-connected back-end project, which I created with Node.js, in IIS.
My example MSSQL connection config file:

```
const config = {
   server: "server name or IP address",
   port: SQL Port,
   user: "SQL Username",
   password: "sql password.",
   database: "sql database",
   options: {
     enableArithAbort: true,
   },
};
```

Here are my codes at the endpoint where I got the error:

```
const express = require("express");
const mssql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
const config = require("./config");

const app = express();
//Customers //

app.get("/getstok", function (req, res) {
   mssql.connect(config, (error) => {
     if (error) {
       res.status(500).json({ error: "There was a problem with the MSSQL Connection", message: error.message });
     } else {
       const request = new mssql.Request();
       const query = `
       SELECT
       STOCKCARD ID
FROM IPLIKKARISIM
       `;
       request.query(query, (error, results) => {
         if (error) {
           console.error("Query error", error);
           res.status(500).json("SQL Query is not working properly.");
         } else {
           res.json(results.recordset);
         }
       });
     }
   });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Normally, when I try it on another server, it works without any problems. I think there is a deficiency in the system, etc., not related to the code, but I cannot solve this problem.

Comment: Please check if the solution in the link below worked for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115632/microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the [SQL Server Native Client RDA 11.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50402) solved my problem.

I have these on my odbc data source manager screen and now my back-end endpoints connected to node.js and mssql are working with the iisnode library.

[image]